# How or why is MSBuild choosing the x64 platform when I don't specify it instead of AnyCPU?

Tags: msbuild, 64-bit

I'm running `msbuild.exe` via Rake from a regular PowerShell console. This is the command as printed from a diagnostic level run

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "D:/Projects/machine.specifications/Source/Machine.Specifications/Machine.Specifications.csproj31881140" /maxcpucount /target:Build /verbosity:diagnostic /property:Configuration=Debug /property:TrackFileAccess=false /property:BuildInParallel=false /property:BuildRunner=Rake

And the build is failing because msbuild is picking `x64` as the `Platform`.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(483,9): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Machine.Specifications.csproj37103470'. Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. **Configuration='Debug' Platform='X64'**. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

I'm not passing it in on the command line (or from the script). The `csproj` has a default configuration

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

and two specific configurations

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
```

So, I expected the `AnyCPU` platform to be selected. But, for some reason, something is picking or sending in `x64`. I don't think the Rake system is a problem here, I've seen this behavior before on raw cmd line calls to msbuild (but I haven't documented them).

I'm on 64-bit Windows 7, calling msbuild 4.0. I don't know if that's relevant.

---

I am [loading](https://powershellcx.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Trunk/Src/ReleaseNotes.txt) the 64-bit Visual Studio tools (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64`) using `Invoke-BatchFile` in my PowerShell profile. Could that be the culprit?

Why would msbuild deliberately choose x64 anyway? The 32-bit version doesn't choose x86 for you.

---

*1: The PowerShell console is at `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
*2: I'm running the [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) build (here's the [rakefile](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/rakefile.rb) and the [msbuild call](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/Tools/Rake/msbuild.rb#L40))

Comment: `MSBuild my.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Any CPU` is another way round (from the powershell prompt)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you launch Visual Studio x64 command window, it sets an environment variable :

```
Platform=X64
```

This is a difference from the 32 bit command window, where this environment variable is not defined, and MSBuild then uses the conditional logic to use default platform.

You can either remove the Platform environment variable in your batch file, or pass in explicit Platform property as a parameter to MSBuild.

Comment: Ugh, thank you. Totally unexpected. MSFT better straighten out their x86/x64 tools story.

Comment: The 32-bit prompt doesn't force x86 platform.