# My x86 Exe runs as x64 when installed as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, x86, 64-bit

I have a server console application that I've designed to run as console app if you specify the /CONSOLE command line, but at the same time allows itself to be installed as a Windows Service using InstallUtil.

My problem is when I run as a console app it correctly starts up as an x86 process and everything works great. But as soon as I install it as a Windows Service it starts up as a x64 process and consequently certain x86 dependant functions fail.

My project configuration is set to x86 and all referenced components are set to build as x86. The actual project itself has it's configuration set to x86 and its target set to x86. Does anyone else have a suggestion as to what could be causing this?

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct version (X86) of InstallUtil. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692753%28VS.85%29.aspx) for an explanation of differences between x86 and x64 versions.

Comment: Hi David, yes, I did use the appropriate InstallUtil.exe. What I've suddenly noticed though is that it shows a *32 in Task Manager, but when connecting using the Attach to Process in Visual Studio it shows as Type x64. Not sure if this means it's running as 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

For Googlers: [Why would a .NET EXE, compiled as x86, run as x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691472/why-would-a-net-exe-compiled-as-x86-run-as-x64) helped me fix my problem like this.

Also, you can use `dumpbin /headers program.exe` to see what it says in the headers. Look for `14c machine (x86)` or `8664 machine (x64)`.